# npm install не устанавливает node_modules

Tags: angular2, npm, node-modules, angular-cli

После команды npm install консоль просто зависает, выводя:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ждал где то пол часа, ничего не происходит. Переустановил NodeJs, версии 8.11.2 и 10.1.0. Подскажите плис у кого подобное возникало.
package.json: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прождал около часа, результат который выводит консоль:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если удалить папку node_modules? А можно код package.json увидеть?

Comment: папку node_modules и не создает, скрин добавил

Comment: попробуй запустить от sudo, бывает иногда такой баг

Comment: Он не может подключиться к серверу с которого качать пакет, попробуй указать другую версию пакета, роскомнадзор блокирует мб

Comment: _Переустановил NodeJs, версии 8.11.2 и 10.1.0_ возможно ваш проект под более старую ноду?

Comment: попробуйте добавить параметр `--legacy-peer-deps`

Answer (score 0):

Была у меня такая проблема, которая решилась пересозданием файла package.json.
Проблема заключалась в следующем: код для package.json я копировал с сайта, в результате чего в некоторых "пробелах" были ошибки, которые убирались путем удаления "пробелов". Первый раз пересоздал файл и в ручную заполнил - все стало работать, второй раз когда смог специально повторить данную проблему и понял в чем причина - просто заменил все пробелы и все стало работать. Так что скорее всего ваш код также был скопирован с какого либо сайта с ошибками в "пробелах".